# How do we utilise SSR in Next.JS, what is 'use client' actually doing per layout/page?

Tags: javascript, next.js, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering, next.js13

**My Setup:**

- Using Verion 13 of Next.JS
- utilising JS not TS
- AWS Amplify
- IDE is VSCode
- Amplify integrated with Figma and Github

***I am new to AWS and Next.JS !***

**My App structure (something like that:**

```
src/App/
    layout.js
    page.js
    aboutUs/
        page.js
    (auth)/adverts/
        layout.js
        page.js
    (auth)/advert/[advertId]
        layout.js
        page.js
```

I assume I should use SSR to get the most dynamic and speedy solution, right?

**My question:**

*When and why do I use 'use client'?*

*and should it be at the top of every file or the main layout or only in places where I want the client to do the work?*

And then why am I being forced to put it into my layout.js?
And what does it mean or why does it matter?
Or should I be tweaking my layout so that use client is not required.

**Here is my layout.js:**

```
import './globals.css';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import awsExports from '../aws-exports';
import { NavBarHeader2, Footer } from '@/ui-components'
Amplify.configure({ ...awsExports, ssr: true });
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'My Website',
  description: 'The Marketplace'
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
          <NavBarHeader2/>
          {children}
          <NavBarHeader2/>
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

**I get this error in the browser (localhost:3000) and similar in the terminal during build:**

```
./node_modules\@floating-ui\react-dom\dist\floating-ui.react-dom.esm.js
ReactServerComponentsError:

You're importing a component that needs `useEffect`. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.
Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials

,-[B:\WorkspaceLocal\AWS\company\git\my-website\node_modules\@floating-ui\react-dom\dist\floating-ui.react-dom.esm.js:1:1]
1 | import { computePosition, arrow as arrow$1 } from '@floating-ui/dom';
2 | export * from '@floating-ui/dom';
3 | import * as React from 'react';
4 | import { useLayoutEffect, useEffect } from 'react';
  :                           ^^^^^^^^^
5 | import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
6 | 
7 | var index = typeof document !== 'undefined' ? useLayoutEffect : useEffect;
  `----

Maybe one of these should be marked as a client entry with "use client":
 ./node_modules\@floating-ui\react-dom\dist\floating-ui.react-dom.esm.js
 ./node_modules\@radix-ui\react-popper\dist\index.js
 ./node_modules\@radix-ui\react-menu\dist\index.js
 ./node_modules\@radix-ui\react-dropdown-menu\dist\index.js
 ./node_modules\@aws-amplify\ui-react\dist\esm\primitives\Menu\Menu.mjs
 ./node_modules\@aws-amplify\ui-react\dist\esm\index.mjs
 ./src\ui-components\ActionCard.jsx
 ./src\ui-components\index.js
 ./src\app\layout.js
```

**It starts complain when I add ui-components to my layout.**
but it refers to deeper react / node files namely **floating-ui.react-dom.esm.js**

**Why doesn't that file have 'use client' in it?**

And if the answer to that question is "because it should be at the top of the hierarchy".

**Then why is it not defaulted**, why do I have to specify it if it is required all the time?
And why does not 1 document/tutorial talk about 'use client'?
nothing advises its use!

**I want to use SSR, and I do not understand how this ever allows me to.**

Answer (score 0):

if you use `use client`, your component will be rendered on the browser. so you will have access to browser api and react hooks. react hooks like `useState`, `useEffect` are used only on the browser because those hooks determine the specific conditions when your component should rerender to show the updated component state to the user. Also, you can attach click handlers to the client component elements.

[image]

this image shows when it is best to use client or server components. server components rendered by the server. servers can be scaled up so that you can use more power to render the component, your component will be constructed on the server, and sent as a JSON to the client, and the client (browser) will show this to the user. so the user will see the component faster.

`RootLayout` component wraps your entire app. In your example, you rendered the `children` component which is technically each page component. elements before or after `children` do not re-rendered. so when the user switches routes for example from the `home` to the `about` page, only the content of `children` changes, the rest of the elements inside `RootLayout` will not be rerendered and state of layout will be preserved. `RootLayout` is server component by default but if you need to use client specific api, you have to add `use client` directive on top.

All the components inside `app` directory are server components by default. the engineers have to determine which part should be the server or the client. This is intimidating a little in the beginning, but then you start to think in depth how to construct the app to get the best performance.  in `pages` directory we do not need to worry about this. Every component is already client component in `pages` directory.

In Server-Side Rendering (SSR), all the components are rendered on the browser, which means that all the components you build are included in the client bundle. However, this approach can lead to larger bundle sizes in the browser, which can slow down your application. On the other hand, when components are rendered on the server, they are not added to the client bundle, resulting in a smaller bundle size in the browser.

- A smaller bundle size reduces the amount of data that needs to be downloaded by the browser.
- the browser will parse and execute the code more quickly.
- Smaller bundle sizes consumes less bandwidth when transferring data over the internet. This is especially beneficial for users with limited or slower internet connections.
- On mobile devices, where network connections can be less stable and bandwidth may be limited, smaller bundle sizes are particularly important. They help minimize data usage, reduce latency, and ensure a smoother browsing experience for mobile users. Mobile usage has surpassed laptops and desktops in terms of internet usage.

if you want to use SSR in next.js 13 you can still use `pages` directory. in app directory, you cannot use `getServerSideProps` or other server functions.

Comment: ThankYou 4 the detailed response!
I want to drill into this part "In Server-Side Rendering (SSR), all the components are rendered on the browser" this confused me. - - - Did you mean SSG? -- SSR is known for compiling what is required and and not sending all JS - - - 

I dislike the term SSR, and I would typically use the term MVC and compiling or processing, and rendering is what a browser does for its user to visually see that webpage.
It should be called SSP server side processing, because no matter which computer (server or client) does the compute the client does the rendering.

Comment: "if you want to use SSR in next.js" did you mean SSG again?

Comment: I want to use SSR ( or in essence I want only the artifacts that are needed in the browser sent to the browser. and hence I want the request to the server to process my JS and serve the HTML CSS and any client side JS. and hence this 'use client' being force on me makes it hard to under stand how I should structure my layouts and pages to achieve this.